# Stash - 2 lists, match/against with a tag not outputting correctly

Tags: stash, regex

Somehow, I'm not able to get this to work. I am populating 2 lists at the top of a template.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="favorites" replace="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
{exp:favorites:entries}
  {stash:item_channel_name}{channel}{/stash:item_channel_name}
  {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
{/exp:favorites:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}


{exp:stash:set_list name="all_channels" replace="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
{exp:stash:get_list name="favorites"}
  {stash:c_name}{item_channel_name}{/stash:c_name}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:set_list}


{exp:stash:get_list name="all_channels" unique="yes"}
  {c_name}
  {exp:stash:get_list name="favorites" match="#^{c_name}$#" against="item_channel_name"}
  -{item_title}
  {/exp:stash:get_list}  
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

I tried just using a static channel name in place of match="#Resources#" but it only outputs 1 item (the same item for each channel loop).

Here's the output thus far:

```
Channel Name: Benefits
Entry Title: 2015 Benefits Open Enrollment Information

Channel Name: Education
Entry Title: 2015 Benefits Open Enrollment Information

Channel Name: Forms
Entry Title: 2015 Benefits Open Enrollment Information
```

It's pretty much exactly like Mark's examples here https://gist.github.com/croxton/6219973 but I can't get it to work as intended. One thing though, when I manually limit the all_channels list to 1 item, it outputs the correct items from the favorites list (I tested it against 4 different channels, one at a time = all correct. If more than 1 item in the all_channels list, it does not work). To be certain it wasn't a server issue, I tried this on my local MAMP machine as well with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mark graciously pointed out](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/14247) that I was missing a nested tag in the get_list portion. I also added the channel_id in addition to the name so I didn't have to deal with needing to character escape names.

```
{stash:item_channel_id}{channel_id}{/stash:item_channel_id}
```

So, the get_list became this:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="favorites" unique="item_channel_id" orderby="item_channel_name"}
#{item_channel_name}#
 {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="favorites" match="#^{item_channel_id}$#" against="item_channel_id" prefix="nested"  orderby="item_title"}
    {nested:item_title}
 {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}  
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another word to your nested stash:get_list, a prefix parameter, and don't think you need parse='inward'. Something like:

```
{exp:stash:get_list 
    name="all_channels"
}
    Channel Name: {item_channel_name}--

    {exp:stash:get_list:nested 
        name="favorites" 
        match="#^{item_channel_name}$#" 
        against="item_channel"
        prefix="st_inner"
    }
        Entry Title: {st_inner:item_title}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: no go still... I put up a revised scenario in the OP. I'm now populating the "all_channels" list from the same list as the favorites, so hopefully eliminate that plugin need.